# Visual Studio Cannot Find MPI Library

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, fortran, mpi

------------------**UPDATE on 5/20/2019**------------------

Following the suggestion by Gilles Gouaillardet, I have compiled my Fortran code with the /NODEFAULTLIB option. Now, I get fewer error messages:

---

Error   1    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __intel_new_feature_proc_init referenced in function MAIN__Test.obj

Error   2    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol for_set_reentrancy referenced in function MAIN__ Test.obj

Error   3    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol for_write_seq_lis referenced in function MAIN__  Test.obj

Error   4    error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mainCRTStartup   LINK

Error   5    error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _fltused msmpifmc.lib(mpifbind.obj)

Error   6    fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals    x64\Release\Hello.exe

---

Thank you.

------------------**UPDATE on 5/17/2019**------------------

So this is a response to the comment by Gilles Gouaillardet. This is only an update to my original question and not an answer.

My code is:

---

```
  program mpisimple

  implicit none

  integer ierr

  include 'mpif.h'

  call mpi_init(ierr)

  !     print message to screen

  write(6,*) 'Hello World!'

  call mpi_finalize(ierr)

  end
```

---

Just to recap, I am using Visual Studio 2012 and I have downloaded Microsoft-MPI v.10.0.

The following directories have been added to the "Additional Include Directories" for Fortran tab:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include\x64

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include

The following directories have been added to the "Additional Library Directories" for Linker tab:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x64

These two files have been added as the Additional Dependencies:
"msmpifmc.lib" "msmpi.lib" <- I also tried these without the quotation marks.

Now I am getting different errors, which have to do with things already defined elsewhere:

---

Error   1    error LNK2005: __crtSetUnhandledExceptionFilter already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll)    LIBCMT.lib(winapisupp.obj)
Error   2    error LNK2005: _calloc_crt already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll) LIBCMT.lib(crtheap.obj) 
Error   3    error LNK2005: _amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll)  LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) 
Error   4    error LNK2005: _cexit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll)  LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) 
Error   5    error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll)   LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) 
Error   6    error LNK2005: _initterm_e already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll) LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) 
Error   7    error LNK2005: exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll)    LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) 
Error   8    error LNK2005: _lock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll)   LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj)
Error   9    error LNK2005: _unlock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll) LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj)
Error   10   error LNK2005: _XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll) LIBCMT.lib(winxfltr.obj)
Error   11   error LNK2005: _configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll) LIBCMT.lib(wsetloca.obj)
Error   12   error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll)  LIBCMT.lib(hooks.obj)
Error   13   error LNK2005: __xi_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)
Error   14   error LNK2005: __xi_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)
Error   15   error LNK2005: __xc_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)
Error   16   error LNK2005: __xc_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)
Error   17   error LNK2005: __set_app_type already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll)  LIBCMT.lib(errmode.obj) 
Warning 18   warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library   LINK
Warning 19   warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library   LINK
Error   20   fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found    x64\Release\Hello.exe

---

Thank you all for your help!

---

------------------**ORIGINAL POST**------------------

I have been trying to compile a Fortran code that uses MPI but I keep getting "unresolved external symbol" errors related to MPI. How do I link MPI libraries properly?

I am using the Intel Compiler with Visual Studio and MPI is provided by Microsoft MPI. The error messages are as follows

---

Error   1    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol MPI_INIT referenced in function MAIN__   ex5f.obj
Error   2    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol MPI_COMM_RANK referenced in function MAIN__  ex5f.obj
Error   3    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol MPI_COMM_SIZE referenced in function MAIN__  ex5f.obj
Error   4    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_IJMATRIXCREATE referenced in function MAIN__   ex5f.obj
Error   5    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_IJMATRIXSETOBJECTTYPE referenced in function MAIN__    ex5f.obj
Error   6    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_IJMATRIXINITIALIZE referenced in function MAIN__   ex5f.obj
Error   7    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_IJMATRIXSETVALUES referenced in function MAIN__    ex5f.obj
Error   8    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_IJMATRIXASSEMBLE referenced in function MAIN__ ex5f.obj
Error   9    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_IJMATRIXGETOBJECT referenced in function MAIN__    ex5f.obj
Error   10   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_IJVECTORCREATE referenced in function MAIN__   ex5f.obj
Error   11   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_IJVECTORSETOBJECTTYPE referenced in function MAIN__    ex5f.obj
Error   12   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_IJVECTORINITIALIZE referenced in function MAIN__   ex5f.obj
Error   13   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_IJVECTORSETVALUES referenced in function MAIN__    ex5f.obj
Error   14   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_IJVECTORASSEMBLE referenced in function MAIN__ ex5f.obj
Error   15   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_IJVECTORGETOBJECT referenced in function MAIN__    ex5f.obj
Error   16   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_BOOMERAMGCREATE referenced in function MAIN__  ex5f.obj
Error   17   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_BOOMERAMGSETPRINTLEVEL referenced in function MAIN__   ex5f.obj
Error   18   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_BOOMERAMGSETOLDDEFAULT referenced in function MAIN__   ex5f.obj
Error   19   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_BOOMERAMGSETRELAXTYPE referenced in function MAIN__    ex5f.obj
Error   20   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_BOOMERAMGSETRELAXORDER referenced in function MAIN__   ex5f.obj
Error   21   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_BOOMERAMGSETNUMSWEEPS referenced in function MAIN__    ex5f.obj
Error   22   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_BOOMERAMGSETMAXLEVELS referenced in function MAIN__    ex5f.obj
Error   23   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_BOOMERAMGSETTOL referenced in function MAIN__  ex5f.obj
Error   24   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_BOOMERAMGSETUP referenced in function MAIN__   ex5f.obj
Error   25   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_BOOMERAMGSOLVE referenced in function MAIN__   ex5f.obj
Error   26   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_BOOMERAMGGETNUMITERATIONS referenced in function MAIN__    ex5f.obj
Error   27   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_BOOMERAMGGETFINALRELTVRES referenced in function MAIN__    ex5f.obj
Error   28   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_BOOMERAMGDESTROY referenced in function MAIN__ ex5f.obj
Error   29   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_IJMATRIXDESTROY referenced in function MAIN__  ex5f.obj
Error   30   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol HYPRE_IJVECTORDESTROY referenced in function MAIN__  ex5f.obj
Error   31   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol MPI_FINALIZE referenced in function MAIN__   ex5f.obj
Error   32   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_DUP_FN   ex5f.obj
Error   33   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_NULL_DELETE_FN   ex5f.obj
Error   34   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_NULL_COPY_FN ex5f.obj
Error   35   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_COMM_DUP_FN  ex5f.obj
Error   36   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_COMM_NULL_DELETE_FN  ex5f.obj
Error   37   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_COMM_NULL_COPY_FN    ex5f.obj
Error   38   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_WIN_DUP_FN   ex5f.obj
Error   39   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_WIN_NULL_DELETE_FN   ex5f.obj
Error   40   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_WIN_NULL_COPY_FN ex5f.obj
Error   41   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_TYPE_DUP_FN  ex5f.obj
Error   42   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_TYPE_NULL_DELETE_FN  ex5f.obj
Error   43   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_TYPE_NULL_COPY_FN    ex5f.obj
Error   44   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_CONVERSION_FN_NULL   ex5f.obj
Error   45   fatal error LNK1120: 44 unresolved externals   x64\Release\Test_MPI.exe

---

The code also uses the Hypre library, developed at the Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory (hence those unresolved external symbols that begin with "HYPRE_"). When I first ran into this issue, I figured it had to do with filename mangling. However, when asked the Hypre library developers, the response I received was:

"These are MPI issues that don't have anything to do with name mangling in hypre (as far as I can see). The hypre library is looking for the C MPI routines while your main program is looking for the Fortran MPI routines, but it's finding neither. My guess is that you probably don't have the MPI library on your link line. You might try looking at some forums that discuss how to use MPI with Visual Studio."

I have tried several combinations of directory paths for "Additional Include Directories" and "Additional Library Directories" in Visual Studio, but that didn't help. The paths linked are:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include\x64

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x64

I should note that the code I have been trying to compile is actually an example file included in the Hypre library distribution, and thus I doubt that the issue comes from any coding error. Nevertheless, in case it helps. the code begins with

program ex5f

implicit none

include 'mpif.h'

All I am trying to do is to compile the code. I have found past posts discussing similar issues but they weren't 100% relevant to the issue I am having. Your help and time will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: How did you install MPI? How did you configure Visual Studio for MPI? Are you able to compile any MPI example program?

Comment: @VladimirF 1. I just downloaded and installed Microsoft MPI from the Microsoft website. 
2. I added "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include" and "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include\x64" as the Additional Include Directories. Also, I added "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x64" as the Additional Library Directories.
3. No, I just found and tried a simple MPI program but I ran into same issue (unresolved external symbol with MPI).

Comment: I found another discussion on how to set up Visual Studio but it didn't help either (https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f04f6ab8-42f5-4045-8b7f-a357bb5fb504/how-to-link-msmpi-with-intel-fortran?forum=windowshpcmpi). 
It seems some systems (like mine) need extra steps to properly set it up. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What did you set as additional dependencies in link tab ? I guess you forgot (FORTRAN)  hypre and MPI ...

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet For additional dependencies, I tried "msmpi.lib" and "msmpi.lib msmpifmc.lib" but it didn't work.. I am currently testing my Visual Studio setup with a simple hello world code without Hypre library but the issue is still there.

Comment: some said the safe syntax is `"msmpifmc.lib" "msmpi.lib"` (note the 4 double quotes and the library order). If the problem persist, please update your question with your code and the new (and smaller) error message.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I updated my question with the code and new error messages. Thanks!

Comment: note there is no more MPI related error message. Do you use the C or Fortran compiler to link your app ? have you tried to use the `/NODEFAULTLIB` option as suggested by the error message ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I am using Fortran compiler (Intel Fortran). I have just tried the /NODEFAULTLIB option and I got fewer errors, but there are still unresolved external symbols. I have updated the post with the new errors. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: can you see how the **linker** is invoked ? I suspect `ifort` is not used ... What if you try to build the binary manually from the command line ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Wow when I tried to compile from the command line using mpiifort it says: 'mpiifort is not recognized as an internal or external command. Does it mean mpi is not properly installed on my machine?

Comment: it means you have to set your `PATH` or use the full path name